# How to install xdebug in ubuntu 16.04 in netbeans?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, xdebug

Whenever I try to run this code

```
example@testserver:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-xdebug
```

I get this error `"E: Unable to locate package php5-xdebug"`
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

If you're running the default `apt` installation of PHP on Ubuntu 16.04, then it should be PHP7. If I had to guess from `php5-xdebug`, then I'd say you were using a command intended for Ubuntu 14.04 or older where the default PHP installation was PHP5. You can verify your PHP version with:

```
php --version
```

This is what I see:

> ```
> PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
>     with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
> ```

At any rate, you should be able to search available packages for your configuration with:

```
apt search xdebug
```

From my relatively fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install without any added PPA's, I get one result:

> `php-xdebug` - Xdebug Module for PHP

So you can install this package by name (note the missing "5" from your command):

```
sudo apt install php-xdebug
```

You might also have to restart your webserver. If you're running the stock build of Apache for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```